ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API and worker service combined in one docker container
In an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API, I can implement long running services with IHostedService interface and have the benefit of having an event stream producer/consumer and Web API in one docker service.
One could argue why not separate them and have, for example, the stream consumer push content to connected clients via SignalR. But let's assume the streamed data is huge and the UI only has to show a very small fraction at one point in time or even better we have a huge amount of existing services which we don’t want to rewrite but introduce event streaming or I want a unified service endpoint for all my solutions/services.
Consider docker base images for Web API and Worker Service are different:

Web API: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
Worker Service: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS base

So considering that a Web API and a worker service are based on two different docker images and each is tailored to their needs, I was wondering what the disadvantages are for running a long running service like an Event Stream or Message Queue in a Web API environment on top of an existing Web API?
As speed and performance is a main concern will it noticeably effect my performance when I, for another example, would want one service that is mostly a background service and on very few occasions uses the Web API?
Just asking for different opinions and their experience in case they have done so.

ASP.NET Core runtime is .NET (Core) runtime + ASP.NET specific stuff, in terms of "tailoring for needs" and docker images it is just "bigger" (the ASP.NET Core image is based on the runtime one).
The main advantage of having web API and background processing separated is that you can scale them differently (number of instances, allocated resources) and load spikes on one not affecting another.
If web APIs response times in general are not a problem, you don't have very strict SLAs and requests are rare - then it sounds to be fine that you have a single deployment combining both. On the other hand ASP.NET Core runtime image will be bigger, so if you have a lot of containers deployed - potentially you can save some resources (disk and RAM mostly).

I was wondering what the disadvantages are for running a long running service like an Event Stream or Message Queue in a Web API environment on top of an existing Web API?

The main disadvantage is that they will use the same resources (CPU, RAM, network) so in case if combined workload is close to resource limits then you can observe one workload affecting performance of the other.
